# Object has no attribute questionNum

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not sure if I fully understand class/instance variables. I have this code :

```
class Question(object):

    """

    Exercise parameters

    """
    input_method = "MathKeyboard"
    difficulty = 4
    dirname = "../../../main/question_factory/int/generated_questions"


    """

    Initialize the exercise

    """

    def __init__(self, cur, new):
        questionFileName = self.dirname + "/" + self.question_file()
        self.questionNum = cur
        with open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), questionFileName)), 'rb') as questionFile:
            self.question = pickle.load(questionFile)

    def question_file(self):
        print self.questionNum <-
        return "difficulty" + str(self.difficulty) + "_" + str(self.questionNum) + ".question"
```

and it is giving an error `'Question' object has no attribute 'questionNum'`
on the marked line. Can you please help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you turn that into a runnable example? You don't need the pickle stuff or paths that don't mean anything on our computers. Just something that runs and demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I don't see any "marked line".  Also, the code is incomplete, since you do not include code showing how you *use* `Question`.

Comment: The marked line was `print self.questionNum` but @tdelaney figured it out, I was calling the function before assigning the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you call `question_file` in `__init__`  before you have initialized its variables. Set the variable first.

```
class Question(object):

    """

    Exercise parameters

    """
    input_method = "MathKeyboard"
    difficulty = 4
    dirname = "../../../main/question_factory/int/generated_questions"


    """

    Initialize the exercise

    """

    def __init__(self, cur, new):
        self.questionNum = cur
        questionFileName = self.dirname + "/" + self.question_file()
        with open(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), questionFileName)), 'rb') as questionFile:
            self.question = pickle.load(questionFile)

    def question_file(self):
        print self.questionNum
        return "difficulty" + str(self.difficulty) + "_" + str(self.questionNum) + ".question"
```

Comment: Good catch!! Thank you so much. I didn't notice that.